# how to compare two text file with first column if match then print same if not then put zero?

Tags: linux, shell, join, awk, sed

1.txt contain

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
.  
.  
180
```

2.txt contain

```
3  0.5  
4  0.8  
9  9.0  
120  3.0  
179  2.0
```

so I want my output like if 2.txt match with first column of 1.txt then should print the value of second column that is in 2.txt. while if not match then should print zero .

like output should be:

```
1  0.0  
2  0.0  
3  0.5  
4  0.8  
5  0.0  
.  
.  
8 0.0  
9 9.0
10 0.0  
11 0.0  
.  
.  
.  
120 3.0  
121 0.0  
.  
.  
150 0.0  
.  
179 2.0  
180 0.0
```

Comment: thanks..if you can help me in answering this question?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: With bash, join, sort, awk: `join <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt) -a 1 | sort -n | awk '$2==""{$2="0.0"; print}'`

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if($1 in a){print $1,a[$1]}else{print $1,"0.0"}}' 2.txt 1.txt
```

Brief explanation,

1. `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next`: Record `$1` of 2.txt into array a
2. If the `$1` in 1.txt exists in array a, print `a[$1]`, else print `0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} {for(i=prev+1;i<=($1-1);i++){print i,"0.0"}}{prev=$1;$1=$1;print}'  OFS="\t" 1.txt 2.txt
```

***Explanation of code:***

```
awk '
FNR==NR{                       ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when 1.txt is being read.
  a[$1];                       ##Creating an array a whose index is $1.
  next                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  for(i=prev+1;i<=($1-1);i++){ ##Starting a for loop from variable prev+1 to till value of first field with less than 1 to it.
    print i,"0.0"}             ##Printing value of variable i and 0.0 here.
}
{
  prev=$1;                     ##Setting $1 value to variable prev here.
  $1=$1;                       ##Resetting $1 here to make TAB output delimited in output.
  print                        ##Printing the current line here.
}'  OFS="\t" 1.txt 2.txt       ##Setting OFS as TAB and mentioning Input_file(s) name here.
```

***Execution of above code:***

Input_file(s):

```
cat 1.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
cat 2.txt
3  0.5
4  0.8
9  9.0
```

***Output will be as follows:***

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} {for(i=prev+1;i<=($1-1);i++){print i,"0.0"}}{prev=$1;$1=$1;print}'  OFS="\t" 1.txt 2.txt
1       0.0
2       0.0
3       0.5
4       0.8
5       0.0
6       0.0
7       0.0
8       0.0
9       9.0
```

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please do let me know the reason for down vote here?

Comment: Not my downvote, but we have a cubic mile of very similar questions. Finding a duplicate is probably a better way to spend your time.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's#^(\S+)\s.*#/^\1\\s*$/c&#' file2 | sed -i -f - -e 's/$/ 0.0/' file1
```

Create a sed script from file2 that if the first field from file2  matches the first field of file1 changes the matching line to the contents of the matching line in file2. All other lines are then zeroed i.e. lines not changed have `0.0` appended.